# How to restart individual servers in thin cluster in rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I have a thin cluster set up to start 3 servers:

**/etc/thin/myapp.yml**

```
...
wait: 30
servers: 3
daemonize: true
...
```

and the I use `thin restart -C /etc/thin/myapp.yml` to restart. However, I would like to restart each server at a time, to reduce downtime.

Is there a way to restart each server by `pid` number or location for example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is something better for you
try option: `--onebyone`

you may also add the following line to your config file

```
onebyone: true
```

afterwards you able to restart you thin cluster without any downtime.

Comment: works great, thank you. Another thing is you might want to increase the `wait: 30` time if your server takes longer than that to start.

Answer (score 7):

I know the question has been answered, but I'd like to add the `-o` option to the mix.

So

```
thin restart -C /etc/thin/myapp.yml -o 3000
```

Will only start the server running on port 3000. If let's say you have two other servers running on 3001 and 3002, they'll be left untouched.

`-o` works with start and stop commands too.